# Getting Tags with Hyphen in - Beautiful Soup XML

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am working with beautiful soup to try and parse some XML however i am unable to use find or find all on tags that contain a hyphen, for example:

`worksheet.find_all('title')`
works fine and gets the tag  and its contents as expected

however

`worksheet.find("customized-tooltip")` returns nothing despite there being a  tag in the XML

im working if it could be caused by some parser issues, i am using

`soup = bs(contents, features='lxml')`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specific the property like that:

```
worksheet.find("child", {"name": "customized-tooltip"})
```

You should replace "child" and "name" based on your xml.

Comment: can you be more specific about what child and name refer too, the XML i am trying to access looks like:
<customized-tooltip>
              <formatted-text>
                <run bold='true' fontname='Thonburi' fontsize='36'>some stuff</run>
              </formatted-text>
            </customized-tooltip>

and is quite deeply nested

Thanks